# Using progress bars of pip

Tags: python, pip, progress-bar

I want use progress bars in my python code. I know there are many libraries for that but I want to use the progress bars used by pip [the package manager]. Please tell if there is a way to do this.

Comment: [Souce code of pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip). It's probably in _vendor/progress and it's used in _internal/cli

Comment: The answers below are outdated. Pip now has a nicer progress bar with color.  more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71923704/new-color-terminal-prograss-bar-in-pip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [progress](https://pypi.org/project/progress/) package available on pypi is used by pip. It can be imported by including the following line in your python file:

```py
from pip._vendor import progress
```

Usage is available on https://pypi.org/project/progress/

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore (pip 22.1), the pip progress bar is now under `pip._vendor.rich.progress`.

Answer (score 8):

Look under [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich#rich-library) `progress bar` :)

Comment: Very nice, but is that what pip uses?

Answer (score 5):

Here, you can use tqdm. And you can customize it to any extent.

https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

Comment: but it needs to be installed which I don't want to

Comment: pip uses it's own progress bar (their own source code), check their codebase: https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py

Comment: is there a way to import and use its progress bars

Comment: Yes (would be quite complex though), depends on how you plan to use it. Take the inspiration from the following codebase https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py. This will be an uphill task.

Comment: I found that pip internally uses [progress](https://pypi.org/project/progress/) for its progress bars. They have copied the whole package inside the [_vendor](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/master/src/pip/_vendor). And there are many more there.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle a little bit to make it work, so for the noobs like me, here is my part.

https://pypi.org/project/progress/ says :
`from progress.bar import Bar` , but there is no bar module there.

I did :

```
from pip._vendor.rich.progress import Progress
```

For my use case, which is having an infinite progress bar while i wait my file to be downloaded, i use it like that.

```
def wait_for_download_finish(file_name,folder):

    " Create a spinning bar until download is finished"

    # Initialize the progress bar 
    bar = Progress()
    # Set a description, and make the bar progress indefinitly
    id = bar.add_task(description="Downloading Files ...",total=None)
    # Start the progress bar
    bar.start()

    # We look for the matching string of the file we wait in the latest file in folder
    latest_file = []
    while file_name not in latest_file:
        # List all the files in folder
        list_of_files = glob.glob(folder + "/*",include_hidden=True, recursive=False) # * means for all. If you need specific format, use *.mkv
        # Get the latest file
        latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        # Keep the bar going
        bar.advance(id)
        # Add some delay
        time.sleep(1)

    # Stop the progress bar.
    bar.stop()

    print("Download finished!")
    return

# Use the os.path.expand if you want to use the "~"  in your path
wait_for_download_finish("test", os.path.expanduser("~"))
```

By the way i discovered the rich library. It's awesome